# Python: Pandas Concatenate each row into a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation

I have the following Pandas Dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({0:["a","b","c","d"], 1:["e","f","g",None], 2:["h",None,None,None]})

   0     1     2
0  a     e     h
1  b     f  None
2  c     g  None
3  d  None  None
```

I like to create a new DataFrame with one column where each row is a concatenated string, with a seperator ",":

```
       0
0  a,e,h
1    b,f
2    c,g
3      d
```

For a single row I could use

```
df.iloc[0,:].str.cat(sep=",")
```

but how can I apply this to the whole DataFrame, without using a for-loop (if possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stacking removes nulls by default.  Follow-up with a `groupby` on `level=0`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)

0    a,e,h
1      b,f
2      c,g
3        d
dtype: object
```

---

To duplicate OP's output, use `to_frame`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join).to_frame(0)

       0
0  a,e,h
1    b,f
2    c,g
3      d
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    print(r.str.cat(sep=","))
```

as a new dataframe:

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame([r.str.cat(sep=",") for i, r in df.iterrows()])
print(ndf)

       0
0  a,e,h
1    b,f
2    c,g
3      d
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    a,e,h
1      b,f
2      c,g
3        d
dtype: object
```